# Put to list of array in to a matrix

Tags: python-2.7, matrix

hopefully it is  simple question......
I have two arrays:

```
>>> X1=[1,2,4,5,7,3,]   
>>> X2=[34,31,34,32,45,41]
```

I want to put these arrays in to a matrix called X:

```
X=[[1 23]   
  [2 31]   
  [4 34]   
  [5 32]   
  [7 45]   
  [3 41]]
```

Expected output is like the following:

```
>>>Print X[:0]
```

[1
 2
 4
 5
 7
 3]

```
>>>print X[:1]
```

[34
 31
 34
 32
 45
 41]

my problem it putting the two array in to a matrix, what I used before is

```
X=[[X1[i],X2[i]] for i in range(len(X1))]
```

But when i try to print

```
>>>print X[:0]
```

I got error like:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

What really I want is when i print
Print X[0] it must outputs [1,23]
print x[:0] it must outputs the first column of the matrix
Need your help....thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot index lists in that manner. Your resulting matrix is just a list. You could create a dataframe to get the functionality you seem to want:

```
import pandas as pd
X1=[1,2,4,5,7,3,]   
X2=[34,31,34,32,45,41] 
matrix = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(X1, X2)]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
print df[0]
print df[1]
```

prints:

```
0    1
1    2
2    4
3    5
4    7
5    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
0    34
1    31
2    34
3    32
4    45
5    41
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Alternatively create a numpy.matrix and slice it as you want it:

```
n_matrix = np.matrix(zip(X1,X2))
print n_matrix[0:, 0]
print n_matrix[0:, 1]
```

prints

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [4]
 [5]
 [7]
 [3]]
[[34]
 [31]
 [34]
 [32]
 [45]
 [41]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can use `zip` if tuples are ok for your need:

```
>>> X1=[1,2,4,5,7,3,]   
>>> X2=[34,31,34,32,45,41] 
>>> list(zip(X1, X2))
[(1, 34), (2, 31), (4, 34), (5, 32), (7, 45), (3, 41)]
```

or:

```
>>> [[a, b] for a, b in zip(X1, X2)]
[[1, 34], [2, 31], [4, 34], [5, 32], [7, 45], [3, 41]]
```

I can't reproduce your last error:

```
>>> X=[[X1[i],X2[i]] for i in range(len(X1))]
>>> print X[:0] 
[]
```

You probably tried to write:

```
>>> print X[:,0]
```

Which is valid using numpy's matrices:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x= np.matrix([[a, b] for a, b in zip(X1, X2])
>>> print x
matrix([[ 1, 34],
        [ 2, 31],
        [ 4, 34],
        [ 5, 32],
        [ 7, 45],
        [ 3, 41]])

>>> x[:,0]
matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [4],
        [5],
        [7],
        [3]])
>>> x[:,1]
matrix([[34],
        [31],
        [34],
        [32],
        [45],
        [41]])
```